# How to Diagnose a Gitlab Connection

Tags: git, connection

## 1. The Problem

I'm trying to push files to a Gitlab repo however, for some unknown reason, only my computer can't do it (my colleagues successfully executed what I was trying to do) when the files go up more than ~10 MB. I have tried many things, including reinstalling `git`, but nothing has changed anything about the problem apparently. Some other configurations that I've tried to change are:

```sh
git config --global http.postBuffer 100000000
git config --global sendpack.sideband false
git config --global core.filemode false
```

## 2. The Error

The behavior I get is given by (gets stuck on 3/5 files):

```sh
Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Writing objects:  60% (3/5)
```

## 3. More Details

It doesn't really matter if I try to upload each file individually either. I've also tried to use `git fsck` but the connection seems to be ok. What I really want to diagnose is if there is some hidden configuration somewhere, something that isn't named with `git` so that I can delete it and start anew (I've already looked for every file in my `Ubuntu 18.04 LTS` with commands like `whereis git*` and uninstalled `git` through various ways such as `sudo apt-get remove git`). By the way, this is not happening when I try to replicate the problem on Github.

Comment: This sounds like a network problem. Something between you and GitLab is breaking things. Are you using a proxy, antivirus, or some other MITM device? Does it work if you try SSH instead of HTTPS?

Comment: I have the same configurations as my colleagues, for whom everything works fine. I don't recall having any proxies, antiviruses or MITMs however. The only thing that's unusual for my PC is the RAM usage, which is strangely high, something that happened in Windows and that still happens and a newly reformatted Ubuntu dual boot, I still don't know why. And we are still not able to use SSH with out GitLab for some unknown reason. We follow the usual steps and tutorials, but it just doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, when I pulled my repo from Gitlab, the remote was being registered with the local IP address of the server, instead of the Gitlab address as usual. Later, when I changed my remotes URL, everything worked fine.

I will leave this open because I think the behavior I encountered is quite weird.